# Printer support for Ubuntu touch tablets

Tags: ubuntu-touch, printing

Does anybody know whether there is printing support for the Ubuntu touch tablet or phone?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer - only a workaround. I use an HP wireless printer with e-print (e-mail the attachment to a set up e-mail address which sends it direct to the printer) There must be a way of doing this in a more direct -not over internet - way.

Please note also this post [how can I set up printing on Ubuntu touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656316/how-can-i-setup-printing-in-ubuntu-touch?rq=1) as this is possibly a duplicate but has not been positively solved / answered yet.