# Installing a printer on ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, printing

can we install a printer on ubuntu touch (OTA 14)?

I will buy the "Brother HL-L2340DW".

In the characteristic, it is written drivers "Linux: CUPS, LPD / LPRng".

Comment: I don't think its possible yet, other than 3rd party apps like Google cloud printer or something like that.

Comment: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/656316/how-can-i-setup-printing-in-ubuntu-touch http://askubuntu.com/questions/792461/printer-support-for-ubuntu-touch-tablets and the bug report on this https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1538701

Comment: @Rinzwind It's going to be complicated, I think I'll switch to android :-( thanks